# Is there a way to restart an Unity app on Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, native

I know it is not a good practice to do so but in my particular case it is exactly what I need : I to be able to restart my Unity application (from a native plugin or C#, doesn't matter).

I have tried the code from [this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/8116915541/) (and even from pure C# [here](https://noodle1983.github.io/2018/11/17/RestartAndroidAppInUnityPureC/)) without success.

Comment: Would reloading the initial scene be enough? [`SceneManager.LoadScene(0);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) ?

Comment: Did you find way to restart app?

Comment: @Whitebrim yes, I just posted my the answer below

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it working with this code :

```
private static void RestartAndroid() {
    if (Application.isEditor) return;

    using (var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
        const int kIntent_FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK = 0x00008000;
        const int kIntent_FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 0x10000000;

        var currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        var pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
        var intent = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", Application.identifier);

        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", kIntent_FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | kIntent_FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
        currentActivity.Call("finish");
        var process = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Process");
        int pid = process.CallStatic<int>("myPid");
        process.CallStatic("killProcess", pid);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working for me (Android 10)!

Comment: Works on my Samsung Galaxy Note 10 as well, thanks a lot!

Comment: Works for me (Android 12)

Comment: No need to mention, but also works for Android 11. Thanks!

Comment: It's working for me (Android 12)

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for this case:

```
    using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    AndroidJavaObject pm = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    AndroidJavaObject intent = pm.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", Application.identifier);
    intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setFlags", 0x20000000);//Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

    AndroidJavaClass pendingIntent = new AndroidJavaClass("android.app.PendingIntent");
    AndroidJavaObject contentIntent = pendingIntent.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getActivity", currentActivity, 0, intent, 0x8000000); //PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT = 134217728 [0x8000000]
    AndroidJavaObject alarmManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", "alarm");
    AndroidJavaClass system = new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.System");
    long currentTime = system.CallStatic<long>("currentTimeMillis");
    alarmManager.Call("set", 1, currentTime + 1000, contentIntent); // android.app.AlarmManager.RTC = 1 [0x1]

    Debug.LogError("alarm_manager set time " + currentTime + 1000);
    currentActivity.Call("finish");

    AndroidJavaClass process = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Process");
    int pid = process.CallStatic<int>("myPid");
    process.CallStatic("killProcess", pid);
}
```

Source: https://noodle1983.github.io/2018/11/17/RestartAndroidAppInUnityPureC/

Comment: Not working, just quitting app. Android 10